# Python 3.4 - Range object index out of range

Tags: python, list, range

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I want to print all of the elements of a list called "my_list."

This code works:

```
my_list = range(75)

for i in my_list:
    print (my_list[i])
```

But this code...

```
my_list = range(1, 75)

for i in my_list:
    print (my_list[i])
```

...generates the following error: IndexError: range object index out of range

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Iterating over a sequence gives you the elements, not the indices. Also, `range` returns a range object in Python 3, not a list.

Comment: @user2357112 you can still index a range

Comment: @AdamSmith: Indeed you can. That doesn't make it a list, and if the questioner tries to do anything with a range object that really does need a list, they'll get more errors.

Comment: Note that the index in the range will be a value of 1 in index 0 and a vlaue of 74 in index 73. so you need to print my_list[i-1]

Comment: @user2357112 it's a useful warning, but it's not what's causing OP's error. It seemed important to point that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just iterate through the list; you're confusing indices with elements.  You one one of the following:

```
for i in my_list:
    print (i)
```

-- OR --

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    print (my_list[i])
```

To illustrate a more severe version of what you did, try this:

```
my_list = range(5, 15)
print my_list

for i in range(5, 15):
    print (i, my_list[i])
```

Output:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
5 10
6 11
7 12
8 13
9 14
10
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 4):

`range(1, 75)` represents the numbers `1..74`. It has indices `0..73`.

`my_list[74]` will IndexError since the largest index is `73`.

---

As other answers have mentioned, it seems you've mistaken indices for values. `for foo in bar` in Python gives you all the VALUES in `bar`, not the indices.

`enumerate` is a common tool to get both index and value from an iterable. It's a bit silly on a `range` object, but you could do it:

```
my_list = range(1, 75)

for i, val in enumerate(my_list):
    print(my_list[i])  # my_list[i] == val
```

`enumerate(bar)` is essentially just `zip(range(len(bar)), bar)`.

Comment: You should also tell him to print my_list[i-1] to get the correct values

Comment: @sabbahillel that's not very scalable for `range(x, y)`. Better to abandon this method entirely.

Comment: I just answered the question as given. however, the use of i-x would handle the general case.

Comment: @sabbahillel in all my time in Python I've never had occasion to index a `range` object. I'm pretty sure the *more* general case is "Don't do this." But that's neither here nor there.

Comment: Probably. I was trying to point out if he wanted to process as he had it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating through every `i` in `my_list`. You want to be printing `i`:

```
my_list = range(1, 75)

for i in my_list:
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple you have to code as below.

```
my_list = range(0, 76)

for i in my_list:
    print (my_list[i])
```

put this code this will clear your IndexError: list index out of range.
[Solved]

Comment: You can add explanation as to why the error `IndexError` is being gotten in the first place.